# How to use PyCharm as a GIT diff tool from the command line?

Tags: git, command-line, pycharm

On the [PyCharm Help Website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-pycharm-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html) I see you can use PyCharm as a diff tool from the Command Line to compare two files. That's awesome! However is there a way to take it a step further and use it as a git diff tool.

So I can just type `pycharm diff file_name.py` and get the GIT differences same way you would if you were on PyCharm have setup the GIT integration and press `CTRL + D` to see the differences.

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can.

First you need to enable the command-line launcher:

> To enable invoking PyCharm operations from the command line, follow
>   these steps
>
> - On **macOS** or **UNIX**:
>
>   1. Make sure PyCharm is running.
>   2. On the
>        main menu, choose **Tools | Create Command-line Launcher**. The dialog box
>        **Create Launcher Script** opens, with the suggested path and name of the
>        launcher script. You can accept default, or specify your own path.
>        Make notice of it, as you'll need it later.
>   3. Outside of PyCharm, add the path and name of the launcher script to your path.
> - On **Windows**:
>
>   1. Specify the location of the PyCharm executable
>        in the `Path` system environment variable. In this case, you will be
>        able to invoke the PyCharm executable and other PyCharm commands from
>        any directory.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-pycharm-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html

Then add the following lines to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
        tool = pycharm
[difftool "pycharm"]
        cmd = /usr/local/bin/charm diff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" && echo "Press enter to continue..." && read
[merge]
        tool = pycharm
[mergetool "pycharm"]
        cmd = /usr/local/bin/charm merge "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
        keepBackup = false
```

(for Windows users these details might be slightly different)

Comment: FYI to all, the Jetbrains Toolbox takeover of making the command line tools has chosen to rename the `charm` script to `pycharm`

Comment: This also allows you to use Pycharm as your git *merge* tool, with `git mergetool -- /my/unmerged/file`.

Comment: @Noumenon indeed, this is mostly what I use it for! I just wish it wasn't so painfully slow to start up, and didn't have to close and re-open for each individual file in the merge conflict...

Comment: I just do all of my merging and rebasing using Pycharm as my Git client, even for Java. This trick is only for files other people committed without finishing the merge.

Comment: Anyone, here's the relevant docs to understand the `.gitignore` file syntax: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file.